# SSRI Medications and Problem solving

Tags: performance, problem-solving, clinical-psychology, bipolar-disorder, anxiety

I'm an Electronics Engineer and I work in Software Development. 
I'm on SSRIs, for years for different conditions, like bipoar, GAD, ..etc.

I feel that my problem solving abilities really dropped down, I would like to know from researchers, do these medications really affect the brain, or it stops it for more thoughts?
For exmaple those medications help for OCD, and that means it really stops or relax the thoughts, I feel the same no care feelings for solving mathematical, algorithmic problems or any thing that has huge brain activity.

I need to know what is the latest research for that area.

Comment: Hello ahmed, welcome to the site! Unfortunetly as per our policy I have had to place your question on hold as "self help" questions are not permitted by our community. Do you think this question could be reworded to be more generic and not as personal? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Memory impairments are connected to fluid inteligence... read this:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16206235

Also consider that stress and ageing decrease fluid inteligence. In addition you said that you care less to solve... it is motivational not cognitive problem.

for real conclusion try to find if you did take any inteligence test (with norms) and try to visit clinical psychologist to compare your new result to old result.

Result from clinical psychologist is most important because maybe you have only impression.